# Whats the best way to have a UIView for a popup Keyboard in a UIViewController?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm currently developing an iPhone application and part of it has a custom keyboard which pops up, this currently consists of

UIViewController
(1) UIButton (to activate keyboard)
UIView
   -- 10 x Input buttons (part of the keyboard)

When the app starts I set the UIView to be out of view, and when the button (1) is clicked the UIView animates up from the bottom of the screen, this works perfectly but it got me thinking "Is this really the best way to do this?".

It would be nice if I could have my custom keyboard separate to the UIViewController so that in future apps I could just include the files which build up the UIView / Keyboard.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is `inputAccessoryView` what you're looking for?

> The custom accessory view to display
>   when the text field becomes the first
>   responder
>
> The default value of this property is
>   nil. Assigning a view to this property
>   causes that view to be displayed above
>   the standard system keyboard (or above
>   the custom input view if one is
>   provided) when the text field becomes
>   the first responder. For example, you
>   could use this property to attach a
>   custom toolbar to the keyboard.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned i'm not using a UITextField in my app i have a label with a transparent UIButton over it which gets the click to start the keypad.

Comment: I'm really looking for the best way to implement my custom keypad across multiple apps instead of coding the keypad in each app I make, currently I am creating a hidden UIView on the screen then when the button is clicked the keypad animates up the screen now I'm not sure if I should be creating a custom control or keeping the hidden UIView separate in it's own xib?

Comment: If I were you, I'd make an invisible UITextField and invoke `[textField becomesFirstResponder]` when the user taps the button.